# Power Automate Flow if a SharePoint List Column value is yes send mail to person1 if Column value is No send mail to Person 2

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

My question is how to create a condition in Power Automate a flow, and it checks column in Sharepoint list if value in column is yes should send email to person1 if value is no send mail to person 2